# Loading dynamic contents when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I hope you can help me with this.
I would like to use a dynamic call to the server to get the content that needs to be loaded to a div.

There is a fixed menu at the bottom of the page that when  tag is clicked calls a function and tells it which frame to update, and then in the function generates an XMLHttpRequest (or use ActiveX in case of old IE versions etc.), with that request navigate to a predefined location on the server where the php snippet lies that needs to be included, and then set that as the innerHTML of the corresponding output section.

I also would like an array outside of the function that keeps track of which pages have already been loaded, so that it doesn't load a page again just because a user clicks on the link a second time.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="FixedMenu">
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" checked="checked" id="main"/>
  <a href="#1">Main</a>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="2nd"/>
  <a href="#2">2nd</a>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="3rd"/>
  <a href="#3">3rd</a>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="4th"/>
  <a href="#4">4th</a>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="4th"/>
  <a href="#5">4th</a>  
</div>      
<div class="scroll">
   <section class="main">
     <!-- loads the main context. -->
   </section>
   <section id="2nd" >
        <!-- this section should load the php file only when the button is clicked. -->
   </section>
   <!-- section 3rd - 5th... -->
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#2").click(function(){
        $("#2nd").load('MyURL'); 
      });
    });
</script>
```

*Is there any chance I can put a php file in the same folder here instead of directing the function to an url?*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
$("#2nd").load('/path/to/my/php/page/here');
```

Have you tried that

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm actually using Elgg for my site. I haven't tried this one yet. Let me check. By the way, the code above loads the url however it loads a new page (with footer and header) within the section. Let me get back to you if your code works.

Comment: if you are trying to load a php script then just remove everything except what you want returned. If all you want to return is the phrase "hello world" then just put "hello world" in the script or the opening php tag and then echo "hello world"; and the ending php tags

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking of that. Elgg has its ready made layout. I would have to code a new php file and direct the '.load' function to that file.

Comment: Thank you Whoopah. This information helps. Can I get back to you guys if I still have confusions?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) it appears that you can. It's still a URL though, as jQuery will still an AJAX request to fetch the given resource. Keep in mind that you want this, as your PHP server does need to parse the file in order to behave like PHP.

```
$('.content').load('dynamic_content.php');
```

**In response to poster's comment:**

Pay particular attention to the part of the documentation that regards to loading page fragments.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Although PHP will still have to parse the entire requested script you can render only a specific portion of it using this syntax and that may help speed things up slightly.

Another thought may be not pointing to a full page, but to an API end point that would return the data you are looking for. This can avoid extra logic for the full page and/or return `JSON` data for easier JS work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do you have any idea how to load it faster? A friend advised me to use xmlhttprequest - it didn't work. Perhaps I was doing it wrong. I'm using Elgg for my site if it helps. Also, the code above loads the url however it loads a new page (with footer and header) within the section.

Comment: The other JS you have running and the execution and the return time of the PHP script are beyond the scope of a simple question like this. We'd need a lot more information. However I will add something to my answer that may help.

Comment: Thank you ToothlessRebel. This information helps. Can I get back to you guys if I still have confusions?

Comment: @EthanGrey Typically you don't use StackOverflow for ongoing conversations about a process. Even long back and forth in comments is preferred to be in the discussion for the question, not in the comments. These should be clarifications or requests for more information. The typical process is if the question has a suitable answer, select the accept button and move on. If you have **another** question while you work feel free to search StackOverflow and ask a **new** question when warranted. I can't promise it'll be whoopah or I that answers, but someone will.  I have been trying to be active.

Answer (score 0):

What you try is the right way.

```
$("#2nd").load('MyURL');
```

`'MyUrl'` should contain your link to your php file, relative to your current file.

If you want to cache the content, you could simply use the second parameter of `load` named `data` to save your content.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes, the code above loads the url however it loads a new page (with footer and header) within the section. Any idea to resolve that? I'm using Elgg by the way. It uses a layout that causes it to load a page within a page if I use url. Another problem is that it stops loading if I keep clicking the buttons back and forth. I think your advise to use 'data' as parameter will resolve the second issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Omeinusch. This information helps. Can I get back to you guys if I still have confusions?

Comment: Feel free to ask any further question if necessary, after doing research ;-)